# NTLM with LDAP/Active Directory and PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, single-sign-on, ntlm

I have the rather thankless task to finish a PHP web application for a colleague who "spontaneously" left the team without a real handover. Final task: SingleSignOn with NTLM and LDAP/Active Directory.

I finally managed to receive a type 3 message from the browser with username, domain and encrypted password. What I don't know is how to validate the password against the LDAP.

As far as I understood, I have to send username, domain, encrypted password and the used challenge for the encryption to the LDAP but I don't know how to do ist. Most solutions I found are for Java. Any suggestions or links to solutions?

Best
Thomas