# Check user credentials in LDAP/active directory with NTLM

Tags: php, apache, active-directory, ldap, ntlm

I have an apache PHP server in which I am trying to implement permissions using an existing active directory.

We choosed NTLM to authenticate windows users automatically, and that part seems to be working, I am retrieving an username and an answer to the NTLM challenge.

I am communicating (with a service account) with the active directory using PHP ldap functions, and so far I can retrieve users groups and check if usernames exists, but I can't connect as the user to verify the password :
`$success = @ldap_bind($ad, "$username@$domain}", $password) or die('Could not bind to AD.');`

Here I can connect with the cleartext password but only have the so called 'NTLM Response Security Buffer'.

Is it possible to chain NTLM and LDAP, and how so ?
Is the PHP `ldap_bind` simply not supporting NTLM ?

---

I read [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/ldap-integration/ntlm-kerberos-authentication) one could transmit both the challenge and the user NTLM Response as a "NETLOGON_NETWORK_INFO", but I cant find any documentation on the way to do so.

I also found [a laravel library](https://github.com/wells/l4-ldap-ntlm/tree/325876bb202c8ad68cec992c4847713360b854e7) claiming to do it, but looking at the code I found what i already tested : the `@ldap_bind` requiring cleartext password.

My issue may be similar to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787287/ntlm-with-ldap-active-directory-and-php), but otherwise very few results associate LDAP and NTLM.

---

Here is the NTLM implementation that was on the server when I took on the project :

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();

if (@$_SERVER['HTTP_VIA'] != NULL) {
    //echo "Proxy bypass!";
}
elseif(!isset($headers['Authorization']) || $headers['Authorization'] == NULL) {
    header( "HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized" );
    header( "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM" );
    exit;
}

if(isset($headers['Authorization']) && substr($headers['Authorization'],0,5) == 'NTLM ') {
    $chaine    = substr($headers['Authorization'], 5);
    $chained64 = base64_decode($chaine);

    if(ord($chained64[8]) == 1) {
        $retAuth   = "NTLMSSP".chr(000).chr(002).chr(000).chr(000).chr(000).chr(000).chr(000).chr(000);
        $retAuth   .= chr(000).chr(040).chr(000).chr(000).chr(000).chr(001).chr(130).chr(000).chr(000);
        $retAuth   .= chr(000).chr(002).chr(002).chr(002).chr(000).chr(000).chr(000).chr(000).chr(000);
        $retAuth   .= chr(000).chr(000).chr(000).chr(000).chr(000).chr(000).chr(000);
        $retAuth64 = trim(base64_encode($retAuth));

        header( "HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized" );
        header( "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM $retAuth64" );
        exit;
    }   
    if(ord($chained64[8]) == 3) {
        //LM Response Security Buffer: 
        $lenght_LMRSB = (ord($chained64[15])*256 + ord($chained64[14]));
        $offset_LMRSB = (ord($chained64[17])*256 + ord($chained64[16]));
        $LMRSB = str_replace("\0","",substr($chained64, $offset_LMRSB, $lenght_LMRSB));
    
        //NTLM Response Security Buffer:
        $lenght_NTLMRSB = (ord($chained64[23])*256 + ord($chained64[22]));
        $offset_NTLMRSB = (ord($chained64[25])*256 + ord($chained64[24]));
        $NTLMRSB = str_replace("\0","",substr($chained64, $offset_NTLMRSB, $lenght_NTLMRSB));

        //Domain:
        $lenght_domain = (ord($chained64[31])*256 + ord($chained64[30]));
        $offset_domain = (ord($chained64[33])*256 + ord($chained64[32]));   
        $domain = str_replace("\0","",substr($chained64, $offset_domain, $lenght_domain));

        //Login:
        $lenght_login = (ord($chained64[39])*256 + ord($chained64[38]));
        $offset_login = (ord($chained64[41])*256 + ord($chained64[40]));
        $login = str_replace("\0","",substr($chained64, $offset_login, $lenght_login));

        echo "$LMRSB<br>";
        echo "$NTLMRSB<br>";

        //HERE i would like to verify credentials against my active directory before accepting the username as a real logged user
        $_SESSION["utilisateur"] = $login;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you choose NTLM? It's basically obsolete.

Comment: If you want to authenticate with AD from Apache, consider using https://github.com/5im-0n/mod_auth_kerb or https://github.com/modauthgssapi/mod_auth_gssapi

Comment: @ADyson I didn't really choose NTLM, but I can change it if necessary. what would you suggest, that could retrieve automatically windows users, (and of course avoid having passwords transiting over http)

Comment: I'd suggest what I suggested in my last comment - those Apache modules are designed to integrate an Apache/PHP server with AD using Kerberos

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the user's credentials to make LDAP requests. Is there a reason for that? Usually, you'd use a service account (a user account dedicated to your application) for making those requests. (even if you are authenticating the user using their credentials first)

Comment: @GabrielLuci, i already have a service accout doing the first ldap_bind (and checking groups and permissions of users) but, as I understand it, i need another ldap_bind in order to verify the user credentials

Comment: But you said, "We choosed NTLM to authenticate windows users automatically, and that part seems to be working." So haven't you already verified the user's credentials then?

Comment: @GabrielLuci no, I retireved the challenge response which is not the password, and I verified the credentials using the hardcoded cleartext password with ldap_bind, but where i'm struggling is using the NTLM challenge response to verify creentials

Comment: I'm confused. When using NTLM, you don't need to verify the credentials via LDAP. The NTLM process validates the credentials for you. Are you able to show the code for your NTLM implementation?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I uploaded the code I found when i took on the project, which used the usernames to get permissions, but did not check the password, only the username.

Comment: Oh, you're implementing NTLM from scratch. There are libraries that will do it for you. Is your server running Windows? If so, you can do this: https://serverfault.com/a/411383/163227 If you're on Linux, it'll be a bit more complicated, but it's still been done.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I was indeed running windows. Since mod_auth_sspi was not running on apache 2.4 i resorted to mod_authnz_sspi, hosted on apachehaus, but since the website closed, i found it in GLPI. I have yet to configure it with my AD, but it was one of the only modules to work with apache 2.4 on windows. Thanks , you may consider adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

> We choosed NTLM to authenticate windows users automatically, and that part seems to be working, I am retrieving an username and an answer to the NTLM challenge.

You cannot verify NTLM responses via LDAP bind.

I mean, you technically *probably* could relay the challenge and response to a SASL NTLM bind, but that's practically the same kind of "NTLM Relay Attack" that your security team usually wants to *prevent* from happening. If the necessary hardening options have been enabled, the NTLM response will be issued for a specific service SPN and will be rejected by the LDAP server. So even if it's possible in theory, it would be very unwise to rely on it continuing to be possible (even more so than using NTLM in the first place).

> I read here one could transmit both the challenge and the user NTLM Response as a "NETLOGON_NETWORK_INFO", but I cant find any documentation on the way to do so.

Yes, but doing so requires an existing "Netlogon secure channel", and *that* requires a machine account.

The usual way of doing this is to install Samba (specifically the Winbind component) and literally join the web server to the domain (which is what establishes the Netlogon channel), at which point you'll be able to use the `ntlm_auth` CLI tool to validate NTLM challenges in the "official" way, by having Winbind relay them to the DC via the Netlogon protocol.

(You don't actually need to install the "user authentication" parts (pam_winbind/nsswitch) on your webserver, in case you're worried about users SSHing into the server; you only need the daemon.)

However, I would **very strongly** recommend against doing anything that involves NTLM. You have *Active Directory,* and Active Directory has had Kerberos **since 2000.** HTTP supports Kerberos authentication just as it does with NTLM, and you don't even need to roll it yourself – all you need is the [mod_auth_gssapi](https://github.com/gssapi/mod_auth_gssapi) Apache module (or the older [mod_auth_kerb](https://github.com/5im-0n/mod_auth_kerb)) and a keytab, and the web server will do all the work; you can just pick up the username from `$_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]` in the PHP script.

(Validation of a Kerberos ticket doesn't even to contact the KDC, nor have any service running nor a special privileged channel; just a keytab containing the password for the webapp's service user account.)